Find the least number that obtained when divided by $A$ and $B$ leaves the remainder $a$ and $b$ respectively. Also $A-a=B-b=d$.
Find the least number that obtained when divided by $A$ and $B$ leaves the remainder $a$ and $b$ respectively. Also $A-a=B-b=d.$
My attempt
Answer given is $LCM(A,B)-d.$
I tried to prove using the division algorithm.
Let $x$ be the desired number. By the statement of the question. We have integers $m$ and $n$ such that
$$x=mA+a~~~~~~0\leq a<A$$ and $$x=nB+b~~~~~~0\leq b<B$$ (I assumed $A$ and $B$ positive.If not I can take the negative of either $A$ and $B$ or both.)
Hence,
$$mA+a=nB+b.$$
Also we have $A-a=B-b=d\implies a=A-d a~~~ \wedge~~~ b=B-d.$
That is $$mA-nB=b-a=B-A\implies (m+1)A=(n+1)B.$$
I don't know how to proceed? Could you help me?

Well, obvious $LCM(A,B)-d$ is a solution.  The only question is it the smallest non-negative?  And you can show that by trying to prove that any two solutions have a difference of a multiple of $LCM(A,B)$.

Lemma 1:  If $X\equiv a \pmod A$ and $X\equiv b \pmod A$ then $X+LCM(A,B)\equiv a\pmod A$ and $X+LCM(A,B)\pmod B$.  Lemma 2:  If $X\equiv Y \equiv a\pmod A$ and $X\equiv Y\equiv b\pmod  B$ then $X-Y$ is a multiple of $LCM(A,B)$.  Lemma 3: $LCM(A,B)-d \equiv a \pmod A$ and $LCM(A,B)-d\equiv b\pmod B$.  Conclusion.  $LCM(A,B)-d$ is the only solution between $0$ and $LCM(A,B)$.

$(m+1)A = (n+1)B = x+d$, this is a Common Multiplier of $A$ and $B$.

By $,\rm\color{#c00}C$CRT = $\rm\color{#c00}{Constant}$ case CRT in the linked dupe: $$\begin{align}x\equiv a\equiv \color{#c00}{-d}!!\pmod{!A}\
x\equiv b\equiv \color{#c00}{-d}!!\pmod{!B}\end{align}\iff x\equiv \color{#c00}{-d}!!\pmod{{\rm lcm}(A,B)}\qquad$$
